# TFS2012 Upgrade - Builds sometimes failing with TF215097 "DynamicActivity" error

Tags: tfs, msbuild

We use a few tweaked Build Process Template, developed for TFS2010 for all of our builds, but these BPTs are *not* using any custom activities. We recently upgraded to TFS2012, and during the upgrade converted our BPTs according to these [instructions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpricket/archive/2012/10/24/upgrading-your-build-definitions-from-tfs2010-to-tfs2012.aspx?Redirected=true&CommentPosted=true#commentmessage).

This works fine, most of the time, but periodically, it coughs up:

> TF215097: An error occurred while initializing a build for build definition \Project1 (Dev10)\Simple - Manual: The values provided for the root activity's arguments did not satisfy the root activity's requirements:
>   'DynamicActivity': Expected an input parameter value of type 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.BuildSettings' for parameter named 'BuildSettings'.

There's nothing in any log, there's nothing visible that I can see as the root cause in any way. The only fix is to restart the Build Controller, at which time the error vanishes for a few hours. When I unregistered and re-registered the Controller, the problem went away for about a day.

The important thing here is that *these build process templates do work on TFS2012*, but then they suddenly stop working for no reason I can determine.

Comment: Have you tried running the build in verbose mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it turns out, some builds were still using legacy 2010-style Build Process Templates. Any time someone queued one of those builds, the entire build controller started freaking out. By getting rid of those BPTs, we resolved the issue.